# stop coroutine don't work in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I succeeded to fade in/fade out  effect in unity.

But i don't stop this effect.

my class  transparency of a game object :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Transparent_Of_Sprite : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    //----------------------------------------------------
    private float duration =  .7f;
    public float waitTime;
    IEnumerator co2;
    Color textureColor;
    // Update is called once per frame void 
    public void start_tranparecncy()
    {
        this.co2=this.blink();
        this.StartCoroutine (this.co2);
    }
    IEnumerator blink() { 

        //Color textureColor = this.transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color;
         textureColor = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color;

        //textureColor.a = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, duration) / duration; 
        //this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = textureColor;
        while (true) { // this could also be a condition indicating "alive or dead"
            // we scale all axis, so they will have the same value, 
            // so we can work with a float instead of comparing vectors
            textureColor.a=Mathf.PingPong (Time.time, duration) / duration;
            this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color = textureColor;

            // reset the timer

            yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);



        }
        //end of if(this.transform.childCount =0)

    }

    public void stop_Transparency () 
    {
        textureColor.a = 5;
        this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color = textureColor;
        this.StopCoroutine (this.co2);

    }
}
```

//-------------------------
my code for stop transparency is ------------------------//

```
Game_Controller.Database [1, 1].Nute_M.GetComponent<Transparent_Of_Sprite> ().stop_Transparency ();
```

don't work for me.please help please

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
this.co2=this.blink();
this.StartCoroutine (this.co2);
```

with this:

```
co2 = StartCoroutine(Blink());
```

You were starting the coroutine like a normal method.

<sup>EDIT:</sup>

Also replace `IEnumerator co2;` with `Coroutine co2;`

Comment: I give  Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Coroutine' to `System.Collections.IEnumerator' error for use your solution ..please help

Comment: @alikarimifard See the Edit.

Comment: @Leststat OP is not actually starting coroutine as a normal method. There are two ways to start a coroutine and store the reference in Unity. You can do it with `IEnumerator` or `Coroutine` reference. The way of is doing it is the `IEnumerator` and should work. Your way should too.