# difficulty in add navigation mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a ui image in canvas in 3D environment .
after add a `navmesh` component  and run  unity,my image  becomes vertical.

[image: before run unity]

[image: after run unity]

I don't know .please help

Comment: Why do you need a Navmesh agent in this kind of game? A work around would be to add a parent to your sprite, attach the Navmesh Agent to this parent, and rotate the child to compensate the rotation of the parent.

Comment: @Hellium I need to move image with nav mesh agent ........in sprite i have very problem for example please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861577/stop-coroutine-dont-work-in-unity/46861913?noredirect=1#comment80673497_46861913

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Im sure you dont need to use Nav Mesh for that game. Im sure with animations you can solve they issue. What is the type of movement that you need?

Comment: @Hellium ............hi my friend......for move Nutes...........